# Getting access violation exception in Visual Studio Community with glfw3 glew and opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I have been having this problem for a while and I cant for the love of me find a solution.

I want to render a simple triangle. But i keep getting this output in visual studio when compiling the program.

NOTE> I do not belive it is not a linking problem but something else. I have checked my linker countless times and everything is there!

LINK: https://pastebin.com/xeTDd0Qu

main

```
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    100.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f,
    150.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f,
    100.0f, 150.0f, 0.0f,
};



GLFWwindow* window;
window = initWindow(640, 480, "Title");


GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);


GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glFlush();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();

return 0;
```

initWindow()

```
GLFWwindow* initWindow(int a_width, int a_height, const char* title) {
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
int err = glewInit();
if (!err) {
    exit(-1);
}

if (!glfwInit()) {
    printf("glfwInit() failed!");
    return nullptr;
}

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", NULL, NULL);

if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    return nullptr;
}

return window;
```

}

Thanks!

EDIT: Exception message i get: 
Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in ConvexHullVisualiser.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

Comment: Do you mean when compiling? Are there more details with the error? e.g. where it got to?

Comment: @doctorlove When running the program. It pops up a window and says that it was violated at glGenBuffers(1, &VertexArray)

Comment: You should step through the code line by line. Then report here in which line the error happens. Also state the exact error message. It makes a huge difference if it states "Access Violation reading ..." or "Access violation writing ..." or "Access violation executing ...".

Comment: I guess the problem is that you initialize glew before creating the window.

Comment: @BDL Oh i forgot to add the actual error... I will edit just give me a second

Comment: At least check to see if the `window` is null, after your init function. Do you know how to use breakpoint in your setup?

Comment: @doctorlove Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you get tells you that you are trying to execute a function pointer that points to NULL. Most OpenGL functions are (on windows) function pointers and are loaded at runtime. In total, this means you are trying to execute an OpenGL function that has not been loaded.

Most probably, this happens because GLEW can only be initialized successfully if there is a valid OpenGL context present. Since the context is created by `glfwCreateWindow`, `glewInit` has to be called after this line.

You are also missing a call to `glfwMakeContextCurrent` to bind the OpenGL context
to the active thread.

```
if (!glfwInit()) {
    printf("glfwInit() failed!");
    return nullptr;
}

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", NULL, NULL);

if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    return nullptr;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
int err = glewInit();
if (!err) {
    exit(-1);
}
```

Note, that `glewInit` does not return an int but a `GLenum`. The correct error check should looks somehow like this:

```
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
  /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
  ...
}
```

[Source: GLEW Documentation](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)

Comment: It now shows the error and it says "Error missing GL version" EDIT: I managed to get it to work! It turns out I forgot to do glfwMakeContextCurrent(window) ! However nothing is displayed on screen...

Comment: oh yeah... I didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: @64humans: I added it in response to your comment. Did it solve the problem?

Comment: Yes but I still cant render anything. I have just done shader compialtion but nothing is rendered i have even tried rendering a simple quad but not even that.. I can just change color of  glClear()