# glVertexAttribFormat fails with access violation

Tags: opengl

I have sources of some game. When I run this game it fails on function glVertexAttribFormat with error "Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in CSC3222.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.".

With the help of the users of this site, I have found that this function was not loaded. This function is actually is function pointer and its value is null.

Why it is not loaded? How I can fix this problem?

I use glad loader.

OS: Windows 8.1
OpenGL version: 4.2

Comment: OpenGL functions are dynamically loaded from .dll supplied by the graphics driver. What you call are actually function pointers (usually hidden by macros), this error simply states that the function pointer was not set correctly. What library you use for the loading? Glad? Glew? If Glew, try adding `glewExperimental=true;` before `glewInit`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting access violation exception in Visual Studio Community with glfw3 glew and opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349863/getting-access-violation-exception-in-visual-studio-community-with-glfw3-glew-an)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I did not notice it earlier in my comment, but `glVertexAttribFormat` is OpenGL 4.3+ function [link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribFormat.xhtml), so you need to use glad loader with that or higher version. It can be generated here [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/)

Comment: Correct answer about version. But the cause of the problem was old video driver. glad.c included in my project actually support OpenGL up to 4.6. After driver update, the problem was fixed.